# Click checkbox with Nested Elements in Watir

Tags: testing, watir, watir-webdriver

I'll try to keep it simple.

I have a list of similar rows like this:

[image]

HTML code:

```
<li ...>
    <div ... >
        <some elements here>
    </div>
    <input id="121099" class="containerMultiSelect" type="checkbox" value="121099" name="NodeIds">
    <a ...>
        <div ... />
        <div ... >
            <h2>Identified Text</h2>
            <h3>...</h3>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

I want to click the checkbox with a certain text, but I can't use any of its elements, because they are the same for all the list, and id is generated automatically. The only thing can be differentiated is the h2 text. I tried :

```
browser.h2(:text => /Identified/).checkbox(:name => "NodeIds").set
```

and I got UnknownException which is obvious because checkbox is not nested with a tag.

What can I do in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The h2 and checkbox are related by the li, which is a common ancestor. Therefore, to find the checkbox, you can look for the li that contains the h2 element. I find the most readable approach to doing this is by using the `find` method of the element collection. The `find` method basically allows you to make custom locators.

The code would be:

```
parent_li = browser.lis.find do |li|
    li.h2(:text => 'Identified Text').present?
end
parent_li.checkbox.set
```

Notes:

- `browser.lis` creates a collection of all li elements.
- `find` iterates through the lis and returns the first element that has the block evaluate as true - ie the first li where an h2 with the specified text is present.

Answer (score 2):

First have a look at this explanation
http://jkotests.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/finding-a-parent-element-that-matches-a-specific-criteria/

Now following a similar approach,

First locate the **element** that has a **unique identifier**

```
parent=@browser.h2(:text=>"Identified Text")
```

Now we have to **iterate over to the parent element** which **contains both the checkbox** and **text against it**.

```
parent=parent.parent until parent.tag_name=="li"
```

Once the control is on the `li` element, simple click on the checkbox using.

```
parent.checkbox.click
```